# How to use generics to be keys of enum

Tags: typescript, generics, types, enums

I am trying to create a generic method for setting web-component attributes. I decided to place my all `ObservedAttributes` of web-component inside enum then use keys of this enum to set web-component attributes, but I do not know how can I define a type for an `Object` whose **keys** will be `enums keys` and values will be `string`.

Let's say that I have this enum:

```js
TextFieldObservedAttributes {
    PLACEHOLDER = 'placeholder',
    LABEL = 'label',
    SIZE = 'size'
}
```

And by basing on this enum I want this type:

```js
type EnumKeyStringValue = Record<'PLACEHOLDER' | 'LABEL' | 'SIZE', string>;
const example: EnumKeyStringValue = {
  PLACEHOLDER: 'text',
  LABEL: 'text',
  SIZE: 'test'
}
```

And that works but I do not know how can I use generics to achieve this. I tried something like that:

```js
protected initialize<T>(props: Record<keyof typeof T, string>): void {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(props)) {
        this.setAttribute(key.toLowerCase(), value);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work because of these errors:

> 'T' is declared but its value is never read.

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

How can I define such generic type ?

Comment: You get the error because there is no value named `T` in-scope. `typeof` in type position returns to type of a value. Why not `T extends Record<string, string>(props: T) ` or `<K extends string>(props: Record<K, string>) `?

Comment: @AluanHaddad first option will not work for me because I will not have hints but your second proposition let me to do sth like this: `type KKWebComponentProps<T extends string> = Partial<Record<T, string>>` which is exactly what I want. Add this second proposition to answers section please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Aluan Haddad suggestion from comments section I came up with this solution:

```js
type EnumKeysNames<T extends string> = Partial<Record<T, string>>;
```

Then I can use this type like that:

```js
function test(props: EnumKeysNames<SomeEnum>): void {
  //...
}
```